# Use <?= and ?> without actually returning?

Tags: php

I want to use the shortcut way to insert some php. I use

`<?= .. . ?>`

But when the function returns true or false, the way with `<?= .. . ?>` prints 1 or 0 on the screen. Is there a way to avoid that and use the shortcut way or do I have to go with the normal php start- and end-statements?

Comment: Use `<?php .. ?>` ..? The "=" means "write the result of this to the output stream". Could also ask that an empty string is written (ie. return it from the expression).. but that seems more roundaboutish.

Comment: thanks, I guess it's disabled though! So I now know how it works and will use the other way, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could always use `<?` for your open tag, but you really shouldn't.  Short open tags aren't always enabled.

Comment: thanks, I guess it's disabled though! So I now know how it works and will use the other way, thanks!